# How to add LED array to 110VAC AC circuit that includes small motor

Tags: led, transformer, motor, ac

I'm building a small machine that uses 110 VAC to power a small (14 W) motor. I want to add an LED array that a switch activated by the motor turns on and off. (The motor will also be gearing some mechanical processes.) Do I need a transformer? And where would that go in the scheme of things?

Comment: `uses 110` ... 110 of what?

Comment: Is the motor 110VAC?  If it is, the easiest and safest way is probably to have the switch simultaneously control power to both the motor and a suitably sized AC input LED driver brick.

Comment: I assume 110 VAC from the "AC" "110" and "transformer" bits. Now for user to crc that.

Comment: The switch is actuated by the motor somehow. What else does the switch do? Are there uncommitted contacts available? And what do you mean by "LED array". You can buy 110VAC panel-mount LED indicator lamps, but I would not call that an array.

Comment: Have you selected a specific LED array?  The potential need for a transformer will depend on the power supply required for that part of the system.

Comment: Where the power supply for the LEDs goes will depend on the rating of your switch.  Which you haven't told us.